# Как максимально оптимизировать (убыстрить) этот участок кода?

Tags: delphi, оптимизация

```
trgba = record
  r,g,b,a:byte;
end;

function q(backcl,forecl):trgba;
var
  factor:real;
begin
  if forecl.a=0 then
  begin
    result:=backcl;
    exit;
  end;

  factor:=trunc(forecl.a/255*100)/100;  // здесь предпологается получить число вида 0,00
  result.b:=trunc(backcl.b*(1-factor)+forecl.b*factor);
  result.g:=trunc(backcl.g*(1-factor)+forecl.g*factor);
  result.r:=trunc(backcl.r*(1-factor)+forecl.r*factor);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function q(backcl, forecl: trgba): trgba;
var
  a1: byte;
  a2: byte;
begin
if forecl.a = 0 then 
begin
  result:=backcl;
  exit;
end;
a1 := forecl.a;
a2 := 255 - a1;
result.b := (backcl.b * a2 + forecl.b * a1) div 255;
result.g := (backcl.g * a2 + forecl.g * a1) div 255;
result.r := (backcl.r * a2 + forecl.r * a1) div 255;
end;
```